# Все комбинации элементов массивов

Tags: javascript, комбинаторика

Мне нужно получить всевозможные комбинации элементов массивов. Например, есть массив а(1,2,3), б(4,5,6), с(7,8). Мне нужно получить на выходе (1,4,7), (1,4,8), ..., (3,6,8). При этом количество массивов а,б,с неизвестно, т.е. их может быть 2,3,4,... Порядок, в котором будут получать эти комбинации не важен.

Comment: Вы, наверное, что-то уже попробовали написать?

Comment: Д Кнут. Volume 4, Fascicle 3: Generating All Combinations and Partitions

Comment: Суть вопросы в том, как заходить эти комбинации? Например, если известно, что всего два массива, то это кодится двумя for циклами, а у меня не известно сколько массивов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать рекурсию - на каждом уровне перебирать все элементы одного из массивов.

А можно сделать цикл со счётчиком от нуля до произведения размерностей массивов. А внутри цикла представить счётчик в системе счисления по переменному основанию (k-я "цифра" соответствует индексу элемента, взятого из k-го массива). В данном случае, например, `i = 8 = 1*6+1*2+0` соответствует комбинации (2,5,7)

А вообще эта задача называется "декартово произведение множеств"